# Illustrator Save Options and useing variable settings

Tags: variables, applescript, adobe-illustrator

Starting to work with Illustrator scripts and trying to write a script that would allow me to change a variable by input and effect the save settings. The save options I want to alter are as followed:

```
-- Save and overwrite
save theCurrentFile in file WorkPath as Illustrator ¬
  with options {class:Illustrator save options ¬
  , compatibility:Illustrator 14 ¬
  , embed linked files:true ¬
  , font subset threshold:0.0}
```

I want to be able to change the compatibility to a variable but no matter what I set the variable as, I can't get it to understand it. I am after something like this:

```
--Variable
set CompatibilityType to "Illustrator 14"

-- Save and overwrite
save theCurrentFile in file WorkPath as Illustrator ¬
  with options {class:Illustrator save options ¬
  , compatibility:CompatibilityType ¬
  , embed linked files:true ¬
  , font subset threshold:0.0}
```

What am I miss that this doesn't want to work. I have done similar things in a properties list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatibility is represented as an enumeration defined in the Illustrator dictionary, not a string. You are trying to use `"Illustrator 14"` to represent the compatibility version. What you need is `Illustrator 14`. Notice the lack of quotes. You can use the following sub-routine to convert a string to an enumeration on the fly. Of course, you can change the string representations if you want. These are just the ones I use.

```
set CompatibilityType to my convertIllustratorVersion("CS4")

save theCurrentFile in file WorkPath as Illustrator ¬
  with options {class:Illustrator save options ¬
  , compatibility:CompatibilityType ¬
  , embed linked files:true ¬
  , font subset threshold:0.0}

on convertIllustratorVersion(originalVersion)
    using terms from application "Adobe Illustrator"
        set versions to {"CS", "CS2", "CS3", "CS4", "CS5"}
        set enums to {Illustrator 11, Illustrator 12, Illustrator 13, Illustrator 14, Illustrator 15}
    end using terms from

    repeat with i from 1 to (count versions)
        if originalVersion is item i of versions then
            return item i of enums
        end if
    end repeat

    error (quoted form of originalVersion & " is not a valid Illustrator version")
end convertVersionNumber
```